# Where do I post questions regarding physics books?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Can I ask a question on physics.stackexchange regarding books?

Comment: [Are resource recommendations allowed? - Physics Meta Stack Exchange](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-resource-recommendations-allowed)

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/book-recommendations  They have a [resource-recommendations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-recommendations) tag there.

Comment: And also [this one, which is specific to books identification](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12955/152812)

Answer (score 1):

Yep.  From the post [Are resource recommendations allowed?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-resource-recommendations-allowed):

> A resource recommendation question is one that asks for a resource (which can be **a book**, website, or other resource) to learn a topic from. It should have the resource-recommendation tag.

The [resource-recommendations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-recommendations) tag is for questions asking, "What is a good book about X", or "What should I read to learn about X?"  Especially look at the "What sort of resource recommendation questions are allowed here?" section from the post above, to help stay on-topic.